# Running bash script written on OS X in Linux

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell

I have a bash script that I've written and tested on OS X. I need to be able to run this script in Linux, however I am currently not able to access a Linux system to test it on.

I know that there are some subtle differences between the syntax on OS X and Linux (such as `md5`/`md5sum` and `-E/-r` for cp), and I was wondering if anyone could suggest a way that I could ensure that it will function correctly on Linux without being able to test it?

Comment: You could just set up a Linux VM on your Mac using e.g. [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org) and use it for testing etc.

Comment: If it's pretty minimal and works on sh as well as bash ... you could go all QEMU in the browser with http://bellard.org/jslinux/ ?

Comment: You can paste it in http://www.shellcheck.net/ and see if something weird is happening. Otherwise, [edit] your question and show the script: we cannot blindly think on what can be wrong there : )

Comment: The differences you describe are not part of the shell itself.

Comment: Technically, it's not a matter of syntax; OS X and Linux have different commands installed.